# If $(X,A)$ has homotopy extension property, then so does $(X\times Y,A\times Y)$?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

If $(X,A)$ is a pair of spaces that has the homotopy extension theory, then so does $(X\times Y,A\times Y)$ for all spaces $Y$. How do I prove this?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a pair $(X,A)$ has HEP if and only if $(X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I)$ is a retract of $X \times I$. Perhaps this could help?

Answer (score 2):

Hatcher, on page 14 of his book, proves that a pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property if and only if $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$ is a retract of $X \times I$. Using the latter characterisation, we can easily form a retraction of $\widetilde{r} \colon X \times Y \times \{0\} \cup A \times Y \times I$ onto $X \times Y \times I$ using whatever retraction $r\colon X \times \{0\} \cup A \times Y \to X \times I$ we have (I guess by just letting $\widetilde{r}$ be constant on $Y$.) This should answer your question positively.

Comment: Nitpick: the proof is on pg. 532 of Hatcher's book.

Comment: Hi Jeroen ! :) I'm not entirely sure this works, or at least there's some subtlety here which is that $-\times Y$ might not preserve the pushout $X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I$. It does when $Y$ is e.g. locally compact (but then it's exponentiable, and the HEP is easy to prove at once in that  case)

Comment: Hey @MaximeRamzi, so I definitely just had in mind that my spaces are 'nice' enough that products and pushouts are just what you'd expect them to be in terms of coordinates. Hm... Products should preserve pushouts if you work in a cartesian closed category of spaces, so I think you'll be fine if you work in the category of say compactly generated spaces throughout. Granted, products of CG spaces with the naive product topology may not be CG but you can 'CG-ify' this topology so as to make the product CG again. I would guess that the retraction maps will remain continuous after doing this.

Comment: Yes, in that case because the CG-fied product is still functorial you get a retraction - and I totally agree that the spirit of the question probably has a nice $Y$, but I just wanted to point out that slight subtlety (in case someone comes along with a Cantor's Warsaw circle or who-knows-what which happens to be a counterexample)